# Grails post giving 400 error

Tags: grails

I'm learning Grails at work, so please bear with me if I seem ignorant at all.

I set up multiple Grails apps through IntelliJ, using the default Hibernate setup, Tomcat server, all pretty vanilla. I created all of the domain models, controllers, etc., via the terminal. Everything works great, and data gets populated from BootStrap.groovy when the app starts. But when I try to post something through the web interface (via ajax or html post), it returns:
`POST http://localhost:8080/BookApp/book/save 400 (Bad Request)`
Absolutely **nothing** shows up in the Grails console, even with everything set to log info.

Here's where it starts to get weird. When I cURL to the save route, it returns a 201 and the data gets populated to the database just fine.

So... where would I even begin to start debugging this problem.

**EDIT**: [Here's a link to the repo](https://github.com/werm/BookApp) if you'd like to check out the source.

Comment: Start debugging by capturing & comparing the payload you're posting in each instance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will be of no help to anyone, but I finally removed everything Java related on my laptop and started over from scratch. That was the only thing that actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a save method in your controller and add a entry in UrlMappings to map a POST to that method. You'r getting a 201 when you do a GET via curl because of the default mapping here:

```
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

Add this :

```
    "book/save" {
        controller = "book"
        action = [POST: "save"]
    }
```

to UrlMappings.groovy

And add this to your controller :

```
           def save = { 
               <whatever you want here>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am too late as nothing has been accepted as answer. I had the same issue recently while posting data with ajax call .
 **The Problem was**, I was sending too much data as request parameter in my request whereas it should be part of the body.

That is it. Simply send your information as part of body and extract on the grails action by using -> `request.reader.text`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Create save action in your BookController and a save.gsp view or redirect it to another action